# Phaser 3 - Unresolved Method Graphics

Tags: phaser-framework, unresolved-external

I'm learning `Phaser 3` with `Webstorm`, and I can't figure out how to fix this remaining unresolved method (see the picture). There are a lot of documentation on how to use the library but fewer on how to setup our environment.

I've set all my environment and most of the unresolved method I had are gone but this one is still remaining: `Unresolved Method Graphics`. If someone have a hint on how to fix that, it would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, I mean I'm not using Typescript but maybe some libraries does so I try to install [types-phaser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@develephant/types-phaser) and it fix my problem! :) If anyone have a more detailed answer I'll be happy to ear it.

**EDIT**

After two day of searching I've found a better explanation. Phaser 3 has no [TypeScript Definition](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/index.html#toc4__anchor) for the time been. We need to install them manually until a further release.